# « Non » ou « non- », quelle est la règle ?

Tags: adverbes, préfixes, trait-d-union

Deux cas vraisemblablement similaires **animé** et **exprimé**. Dans la phrase ci-dessous, tirée d'un livre, pourquoi non-animé (avec trait d'union) et non exprimé (sans cela) ?

> Ils se renvoient à des noms non-animés déjà exprimés ou non
> exprimés...

Comment: Besides Stéphane's answer, I note that *animé* describes an essential quality and *exprimé* an action. But Stéphane's last line would be a counterexample, so perhaps it's not relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Non* est en général utilisé en tant que préfixe pour les noms. Il est dans ce cas relié à ceux-ci avec un trait d'union (par exemple, *non-sens*), ou dans certains cas directement accolé (*nonchalance*).

Devant un adjectif, *non* est le plus souvent un mot en lui-même et a le rôle d'adverbe.

*Non-animé* est un cas un peu particulier car la terminologie grammaticale en fait souvent un nom (*un animé* s'oppose à *un non-animé*), mais dans des textes moins techniques on s'attend généralement à une négation verbale (*un être non animé*), ou au terme *inanimé* qui est l'opposé plus habituel (*un corps inanimé*).

---

*Non* is generally used as a prefix for nouns, in which case it is usually connected to it with a hyphen (e.g. *non-sens*), although it is sometimes directly concatenated to it (*nonchalance*).

Before an adjective, *non* is most often a word on its own, used as an adverb.

*Non-animé* is kind of an edge case as grammar terminology sometimes makes it a noun (*un animé* vs *un non-animé*), but outside of technical reading one would expect a verbal negation (*un être non animé*), or *inanimé* which is the more usual counterpart (*un corps inanimé*).

Comment: So here non-animé is considered noun ? Non exprimé is adjective ? I like your answer but I am missing something:-)! (Thanks a lot for the response.)

Comment: @dimitris: The status of *non-animés* in *noms non-animés* is rather unclear. It's a more of a shortcut than a properly constructed phrase. You should probably not focus too much on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que la différence est syntaxique mais non-essentielle.

- Des noms non-animés = des noms innanimés
- Des noms non animés = des noms qui ne sont pas animés
- Des noms non-exprimés = des noms inexprimés
- Des noms non exprimés = des noms qui ne sont pas exprimés.

Non avec tiret transforme le nom, alors que non sans tiret transformant le verbe (ici sous entendu qui sont).